# Fill remaining space without enforcing height

Tags: html, css

I'm builiding a webapp that's meant to contain simple interactive panels.

My goal is to have a single #container that's scrollable when overflowed and #panels inside of it that are also scrollable to prevent overflow of the parent (#container) when possible.

In other words:

- if there's 1 panel: fill the remaining height
- if there's 1 panel and it has a very big table whose rows could overflow the panel: fill remaining height and show scroll on the panel
- if there are 10 panels and they simply can't all fit: show scroll on #container

Here's the code:

```css
    .container
    {
        background: red;
        padding: 16px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 128px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }

    .panel
    {
        background: green;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        display: flex;
        flex-grow: 1;
        flex-direciton: column;
    }

    .table-container
    {
        background: blue;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            Scenario: One table
            <br>
            This should shrink table and only show a scrollbar on the panel (green)
        </p>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='panel'>
                <div class='table-container'>
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>
            Scenario: Two elements that can fit in one container
            <br>
            This should shrink table, show scroll on it's panel and display second element just fine
        </p>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='panel'>
                <div class='table-container'>
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='panel'>
                B
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>
            Scenario: Three elements that can't fit in one container
            <br>
            This should shrink table and show scrollbar on it's panel, while also displaying a scrollbar on the container
            because these 3 can't fit in the container
        </p>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='panel'>
                A
            </div>
            <div class='panel'>
                <div class='table-container'>
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='panel'>
                B
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you assume that it should change with specific number of children? Because then you can consider making your container a flexbox and switching from `flex-shrink: 10000` to `flex-shrink: 0;` for your children using quantity selectors: https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css/

Comment: @MichałSadowski sadly, there won't be a specific number as every view will contain different amount of panels and they'll also be added on the go.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, if you know at how many panels you might want to switch or if their height is also to much of a variable for that.

Comment: Do you have a code sample I could try it on? @MichałSadowski